# PraseGeoPoint does not retrieve images within location Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

```
package com.google.geoplace;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseGeoPoint;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    // Declare Variables
    protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    ListView listview;
    List<ParseObject> ob;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    Context context;
    private List<PlaceFilter> worldpopulationlist = null;
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(location!= null) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    // RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Custom ListView Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // Create the array
            worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<PlaceFilter>();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23&&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

            try {
                // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                        "geo_filters");

                // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
                // by ascending

                ob=query.find();
                for (ParseObject PlaceLocation : ob) {
                    // Locate images in flag column
                    ParseFile image = (ParseFile) PlaceLocation.get("FilterFile");
                    PlaceFilter map = new PlaceFilter();
                    ParseGeoPoint userLocation = new ParseGeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
                    query.whereNear("PlaceLocation", userLocation); //column as location
                    query.whereWithinKilometers("PlaceLocation", userLocation, 1);
                    map.setPlaceName((String) PlaceLocation.get("PlaceName"));
                    map.setFilterFile(image.getUrl());
                    worldpopulationlist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e){
                Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    worldpopulationlist);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

I trying to return images from parse within the kilometer radius of their location. I am retrieving the latitude and longitude but it does not filter images in the Parse Cloud. You can find my Parse Classes here:

[image]

Comment: What is it giving to you? BTW, you don't need to define AsyncTask if you do findInBackground with a callback instead of find

Comment: Its returning all the images from the Parse Cloud. It does not filter images within the location radius @Iliiaz Akhmedov

Comment: Change 1st Record ACL permission to read & write.& check your current location lat lng its nearest to data base .
or change query like query.whereWithinKilometers("PlaceLocation", userLocation, 200);

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't override the global variables of latitude and longitude, but create local ones, thus, never set them into the query:

```
    if(location!= null) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
```

Should be:

```
    if(location!= null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
```

Comment: Still I am not able to retrieve geo location filtered images from the cloud.

Comment: @SagarAtalatti What is the location you are giving to the query and what is the PlaceName? Are you sure they match the query? Give some samples

Comment: PlaceName is the Parse Class as you see in the Parse screenshot.  I want the Images to be filtered by ParseGeoPoint where the latitude and longitude have been defined for each. I want to get location of the users to get images within their location radius only @Iliiaz Akhmedov

Comment: I am trying to get latitude and longitude of the current user and I want to send the latitude and longitude to the parse cloud and return the images within the user's location radius.

Comment: I was saying provide real examples that you are giving to the program, maybe, you are missing some spaces in the string or simply geolocation is out of the radius